# Styled-Components apply style based on ID

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Say I have a StyledButton with the following structure;

```
<StyledButton className={`button-${id}`}>{content}</StyledButton>
```

Where StyledButton is

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  ...
`;
```

I would like to specify additional styles to be applied if the Button className equals a value. Which selector could I use within StyledButton to apply styles if the StyledButton has a specified class?

Answer (score 5):

You can always add inline functions inside the template literal of Styled Components. You receive [`props`](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) as the first argument.

```js
const StyledButton = styled.button`
    ${props => props.className === 'foo-bar' && css`
        color: red;
    `};
`;
```

If you're not sure which `props` you're getting, you can easily check by:

```js
const StyledButton = styled.button`
    ${console.log};
`;
```